Подключиться из приложения на PyQT5 к чату на Django
У меня есть проект на Django, где с помощью Channels + Redis реализован чат. Появилась необходимость в создании GUI приложения для Windows с интеграцией этого чата туда. Попробовал реализовать связь через:
self.con_web_socket = QWebSocket("", QWebSocketProtocol.Version13, None)
self.con_web_socket.errorString()
self.con_web_socket.open(QUrl("wss://url_my_site/ws/room_name"))

Ошибок нет но, данные из чата с сайта не прилетают, как и не летят данные на сайт.
В JS это работает отлично:
var ws_scheme = window.location.protocol == "https:" ? "wss" : "ws";
const chatSocket = new WebSocket(ws_scheme + '://' + window.location.host + '/ws/room_name/');
chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({'message': textNewMsg,'username': fullName}));

Пытался реализовать не что подобное.
